# Hibernate tools: persistence unit not found

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-tools

I have created a Hibernate / JPA project and I'd like to create entities from tables.

While the tool works like a charm selecting a pure Hibernate configuration, in the JPA mode it does not work, claiming the absence of the persistence unit

As shown in the following photo, the persistence unit is located in the folder */src/main/resources/META-INF*

[image]

This is the code of persistence.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="socialsports" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/LiveDataSource</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is the result of my attempt to run Hibernate tools to generate entities:
[image]

Comment: What happen if you move the persistence.xml to the META-INF in the src/main/java? it works ?

Comment: Already tried. Same error :(

Comment: My project has similar settings and I got the same error. Tried moving the persistence.xml file to different places with no success. =/

Comment: @user1550958 The same for me, has anybody managed to solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Since it only doesn't work in JPA mode, the use of the deprecated `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistenceProvider` could be a problem. Try `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` instead.